# JQuery $("#content").append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn JQuery, but not doing well. Currently, I'm trying to learn how to use `.append` to have Ajax functionality which allows one to view new dynamic content without reloading. When I try the following, however, nothing occurs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JQuery Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function callback() {
    $("#content").append($("qwerty"));
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    //window.setTimeout(callback, 100);
    callback();
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

To the best of my knowledge, this should make "qwerty" appear as if I has simply done `<div id="content">qwerty</div>`, but instead I get a blank page. If I replace the `.append` call with `alert("qwerty")`, it is properly displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to find an element with tagname `qwerty` in the dom like `<qwerty>sometext</qwerty>` and append it to `#content`.

To append the string `qwerty` to `#content` use

```
$("#content").append("qwerty");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7jBcr/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#content").append("qwerty").
```

Just remove $ simple in your coding.. if you want to append text, you can directly pass the text in double quotation